# I am stuck, mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have a problem with a code in php it shows me this as errors.
register

> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\search_engine\insert.php on line 99

And this is the code :

```
<?php

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=srgn;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '123456');

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $s_link = $_POST["s_link"];
        $s_key = $_POST["s_key"];
        $s_des = $_POST["s_des"];
        {
          $sql = "insert(site_link, site_key, site_des) values('$s_link', '$s_key', '$s_des')";

          $rs = mysqli_query($sql);

          if($rs)
          {
            echo "<script> alert('Site uploaded successfully') </script>";
          }

          else

           {
            echo "<script> alert('Uploading failed, please try agin.') </script>";
           } 
        }
    }


?>
```

Where is the error please, and how can I set it?

Comment: Try to explain what are you trying to do with your code and what you've already tried to solve this (even if it didn't work).

Comment: What error?  The message has `Warning`, and tells you what is wrong, so see the [mysqli API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) info for more details, and you'll discover what's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass on the connection link as the first parameter and the SQL query as the second parameter.  This is required as you are doing procedural code. Refer to the link below for more details
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php